# Google map api: map center changed automatically

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have developed sencha extjs application. As per my requirement, I have to show google map. The center of the map should be set as data from server. I used google map api for the above.

The center position of the map is being changed automatically when I come back to same page again. There are no changes in data. I checked very well. Meaning map is moving up and left also.

I used following code in my home page of the ExtJS app.

```
<script id="google" type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I used the following set of lines of code in my javascript class. This is being called when map is being shown in the extjs app.

```
var map = new Ext.create('Ext.Map',{
height: '100%',
mapOptions : {
  center : new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
  zoom : 11,
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  navigationControl: true,
  navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
}
}
});
this.add(map);
```

Comment: We need a link to your map page to debug this.

Comment: Does the map have a size?  What is the height of its containing element?

Comment: I think it is the Sencha touch bug which i already posted here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?276745-Two-initalized-map-components-lead-two-centering-of-wrong-position-of-second-map

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are only dealing with one instance of the Map and not recreating it without properly destroying the first. The known bug mentioned seems to only impact multiple maps. To be sure you are not creating multiple instances, just run this in JS console: **Ext.ComponentQuery.query('map')**. If it returns with more than one result, that's probably the issue.

Otherwise, make sure you have the **useCurrentLocation** property disabled on the map. Call the **getGeo** method on the map component and make sure there isn't a geolocation util somehow set on the map that is overriding location detection.

If all else fails, just add a show listener/painted to your map (maybe with a slight delay) that re-centers the map.